# Vs and Resharper intellisence works together

Tags: visual-studio-2015, resharper

Today I install resharper on vs 2015. When I type something and then `.` both vs and resharper intellisence works. How can I disable vs intellisence?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

go to `tools>options>text editor>all languages>general` and uncheck `Auto list members`

This will disable visual studio intellisence